# Grails - view not recognising model

Tags: grails, view, gsp

I've got a controller, which is getting a list of objects associated with a user and passing it to the view using the render method, like so:

```
class HomeController {
def index() {
    def postList = user.posts

    postList.each{ it ->
      println "Title: " + it.title
    }

    render(view: "/index", model: [returnPosts: postList])
}
```

In my view I have the following code:

```
<h2>Recent Posts:</h2>
<ul>
  <g:each var="post" in="${returnPosts}">
    <li><g:link controller="post" action="show" id="${post.id}">${post.title}</g:link></li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
```

Now, in my controller, I've put in the 'println' statements to ensure that the list is not null, and sure enough it's not. However, when I open the page, the g:each tag doesn't run even once as if the "returnPosts" variable is null, even though in the controller the println statments show that it's not.

I've been going crazy trying to figure this out, can anyone see any reason why the view wouldn't have access to this variable?

Comment: try a `<% System.out.println "returnPosts : " + returnPosts %>` in the GSP. Writing directly to the console Output saved my life several times... That's the first thing to do, see if returnPosts in indeed null when entering the View

Comment: everything seems correct. maybe you've made a typo somewhere?

Comment: If you are using a Grails version less than 2.0.0, the problem is with your action declaration. You have `def index() {` when you should have `def index = {`. Since Grails doesn't recognize that as a valid action, it skips the controller and renders the `.gsp` file directly and the model is never populated. If you are using Grails 2.0.0, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try using `view: "index"` instead of `view: "/index"`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a controller attribute called 'post' and also your g.each var is 'post'. Potential problem there?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you could do to fix this problem. Firstly, if your view is called index.gsp then you don't need to explicitly call render, returning a list of model objects would do. Your code will look like this:

```
def index() {
    def postList = user.posts

    postList.each{ it ->
      println "Title: " + it.title
    }
  [returnPosts: postList]
}
```

Another thing you could also do is to explicitly import the model object that you are accessing in the view. Not that it matters, but you could try using a name other than post, given that it is a common word. So your gsp will look like this :

```
<%@ page import="com.blah.post" %> 
<h2>Recent Posts:</h2>
<ul>
  <g:each in="${returnPosts}" var="post">
    <li><g:link controller="post" action="show" id="${post.id}">${post.title}</g:link></li>
  </g:each>
</ul>
```